# Porque é que são permitidas, no Brasil, palavras como "leiaute"?

Tags: estrangeirismos, português-brasileiro

Porque é que são permitidas, no Brasil, palavras como [**leiaute**](http://www.dicio.com.br/leiaute) se poderíamos perfeitamente usar o estrangeirismo ***layout***?

Afinal, escrever [**leiaute**](http://www.dicio.com.br/leiaute), é escrever como se lê ***layout***.

Existem mais algumas palavras assim como *skatista*, *eslaide*, se alguém puder comente com mais palavras do género, por favor.

Comment: Nunca vi essa forma ortográfica no Brasil e nem em Portugal.  Se alguém encontrou a palavra "leiouti", devem ter sido casos isolados.  Transliteração é uma coisa, escrever errado é outra.  Muita gente escreve errado no Brasil.

Comment: @Centaurus http://www.dicio.com.br/leiaute

Comment: @JorgeB. É verdade. Nunca havia visto essa forma aportuguesada.

Comment: Isso se usa porque o pessoal não sabe que layout é diagramação e que a palavra é mais comprida: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagrama%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Comment: @Lambie diagramação não é layout. Pelo menos não encontrei ligação na minha pesquisa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Geralmente (mas não necessariamente sempre) quando palavras em inglês são transliteradas para o português, a intenção é facilitar a compreensão de quem pode não saber a pronúncia de palavras em inglês, podendo ler, por exemplo, "layout" como "laiouti". E a pessoa pode ter ouvido falar nisso mas não lido, e para ela continuar sabendo o que é, mesmo não sabendo a pronúncia correta da palavra, usa-se a transliteração.

Eu já vi uma vez em um gibi da Turma da Mônica em que foi usado "esqueite", e eu que era criança na época, achei bizarra essa transliteração.

Outra situação onde isso é visto, são em traduções para o português feitas de forma muito literal, preservando os termos em inglês, mas transliterando-os.

Mas são muito pouco usadas essas transliterações.

Comment: Eu li a mesma edição, eu lembro de ter lido "esqueite". Eu fiquei dois minutos tentando entender  se aquilo estava certo.

Comment: Espero que não vire moda, pra mim é uma aberração.

Comment: A intenção foi facilitar e acabou piorando mais ainda. Eu lembro que eu fiquei "ahn? Esqueite? Por que não usar skate?" As crianças sabem o que é skate, não precisa disso.

Comment: Isso é visto por muita gente como desnecessário, mas ainda assim tem gente que vê uma necessidade pra isso.

Comment: @BrunoLopes O melhor era instruir as pessoas a saberem falar inglês e não destruír o português.

Answer (score 5):

Não creio que seja questão de ser "permitido". A língua não pede permissão pra ninguém e chega ao ponto que obriga o dicionário a incorporar certa palavra.

E o Brasilsão abusa tanto, mas tanto:

### Como é que se diz pleigraunde <sup>`*`</sup> em Inglês? *Fun floor*, ora bolas!

[image]

<sup>`*` Playground</sup>

Comment: Inclusive dizem que o Verbo é uma entidade viva e aparte e que não somos nós que dominamos a Língua, ao contrário :)

Comment: Não posso acreditar no que estou a ver...

Comment: @JorgeB., atenção especial à parte de Portugal e das Gravatas :p [Amalia/Vinicius - disco que regista o encontro de Vinicius (e mais poetas) em casa de Amália (1970)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48fjovsY7R0)

Comment: Não entendi @brasofilo

Comment: @JorgeB., antes de mais nada, é um clássico que deviam colocar pra gente na escolinha :) O que me refiro é a parte onde o Vinícius analisa o caráter português, comparando com a gravata. É mais bem um disco pra uma manhã de domingo.

Comment: Fiz uma resposta citando essa faixa, acho que o que o Vinicius diz é fundamental no estudo dos caracteres PT e BR: [Por que o idioma português Portugal não aceita palavras estrangeiras?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/589/135)

Comment: Não seria melhor se escrevesse _"pleigraunde"_?

Comment: @Math, yes, sir, ¡ferpectamente!

Answer (score 3):

Acho que não há uma (só) lógica. Algumas palavras são aportuguesadas (futebol, leiaute, pênalti, deletar, locaute, blecaute), outras continuam como estrangeirismos (*skate*, *slide*, *loop*, *footing*, *playground*, *software*), outras ainda são rejeitadas por desnecessárias (*centeraufo*, *hostel* - pelo menos no Brasil), outras são adotadas temporariamente e depois descartadas em prol de algum neologismo ou outro empréstimo (*corner*/córner, substituída por escanteio, *back*/beque, por zagueiro). E às vezes o aportuguesamento respeita a forma falada, como leiaute, e outras a forma escrita, como rúgbi. E há as que são adotadas mas passam a designar algo diferente, como o caso de "motel", originalmente "hotel barato, de beira de estrada", que, não sei bem por quê, virou "hotel para encontros sexuais".

Me parece que verbos tenderão a ser aportuguesados mais rapidamente, por causa da conjugação (*delete* não pode continuar "delete" por que precisamos de deleto, deletei, deletáveis, deletaríamos - a não ser que seja substantivado, *dá um delete aí*).

E com certeza as palavras que são aportuguesadas respeitando a forma escrita são empréstimos literários; aquelas que são aportuguesadas respeitando a forma falada são empréstimos orais, falados antes de serem escritos.

Ainda parece que há dinâmicas diferentes no Brasil e em Portugal. Por quê diabos  "o idioma português Portugal não aceita palavras estrangeiras" e aí me aceita substituir o bom, velho e castiço português "albergue" por *hostel*, enquanto a casa da mãe Joana que é o Brasil, onde tudo se importa sem que ninguém se importe, rejeita semelhante absurdo e segue firme com albergue, pousada, abrigo? Mistério... pelo menos para mim.

Comment: Gostei muito da tua resposta, dá que pensar. Mas porque usar deletar quando já existia apagar que é a tradução livre de delete? É meio estranho, só isso...

Comment: @JorgeB. - Obrigado. Talvez por modismo, ou talvez para marcar a diferença entre "apagar" algo que está realmente escrito, preto no branco, tinta no papel, e "deletar" algo que só tem existência virtual? Não sei, e não sei por que uma coisa ocorre no Brasil e outra em Portugal.

Comment: A do *hostel* é certamente por ser mais *cool*, é a moda aqui. Se calhar é mesmo só isso, uma moda. Eu quando fiz esta pergunta era mais conservador no português, agora já sou um bocadinho menos, porque a verdade é que quem faz a língua são as pessoas.

Comment: @JorgeB. - Não sei, talvez os portugueses vejam alguma diferença, para eles importante, entre "hostel" e albergue/pousada/hospedaria, que os brasileiros não vêem... Talvez coisa de um país com mais turistas, onde é importante demarcar "espelunca pseudo-sofisticada para uso de otários estrangeiros" de "espelunca sem pretensões, para uso dos nacionais, que sabem que estão a ser tungados"?

Comment: Talvez seja mesmo isso...

Answer (score 2):

Porque existe uma imensidão de [estrangeirismos na lingua portuguesa](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=loanwords&act=list) e sem aportuguesamentos seria um pesadelo decorar a grafia de todos eles, um bocado à semelhança do que acontece no inglês.

Por exemplo, a maioria das pessoas não iria saber como ler [yacht](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/iate).

Comment: Excelente perspetiva essa, tive de ir ver o que é "yacht".