# Por que o português europeu não incorpora muitos estrangeirismos?

Tags: ortografia, português-brasileiro, português-europeu

Aqui no Brasil palavras estrangeiras, termos de informática, por exemplo, são muito empregados e com tempo são incorporados à língua.
Observando os *menus* de programas de computadores com idioma português Portugal, pude notar as diferenças.

> Exemplos:
>
> Brasil    /   Portugal
> Arquivos (*files*) -> Ficheiros
> Salvar (*save*) -> Guardar
> Deletar (*delete*) -> Apagar
> Mouse -> Rato de computador
> e-mail -> Correio electrónico

Por que existem estas diferenças?

Comment: Na verdade eles usam sim: "layout", "t-shirt", dentre outras..

Comment: A pergunta melhor é porque é que os brasileiros as inventaram. :P

Comment: @E_net4 Os espanhóis dizem que *“Los ficheros se guardan, las vidas se salvan, y el dinero se ahorra.”*  (Não sei se o último verbo, *ahorrar*, tem uma versão especial no português.)

Comment: Relacionada: [Porque é que são permitidas, no Brasil, palavras como “leiaute”?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/449/porque-%C3%A9-que-s%C3%A3o-permitidas-no-brasil-palavras-como-leiaute)

Comment: @tchrist _Aforrar_, mas é pouco usado.

Comment: *Ahorrar* é/is "economizar" ou/or "poupar".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Isso acontece porque no Brasil é costume transliterar algumas palavras do inglês para o português.

> Exemplos: esporte (*sport*), deletar (*delete*), leiaute (*layout*), salvar (*save*), usuário (*user*), etc.

Não são propriamente palavras estrangeiras.

Arquivo também se usa em Portugal, só que no sentido de "arquiva esse processo que já está encerrado".

O *mouse* (ainda bem que não é mausi) não se usa porque tem tradução fácil para português, "rato".

Nós até usamos alguns estrangeirismos, mas atualmente, não costumamos "aportuguesar" o inglês.

> Exemplos: *layout*, *t-shirt*, *e-mail*, *shampoo*, *skate*, etc.

Costumamos usar estrangeirismos só quando a tradução não é fácil.

---

*Mas que eu saiba não "aportuguesamos" muitos termos e, eu acho que não tem muita lógica fazê-lo, mais vale ensinar inglês às pessoas do que inventar palavras para facilitar.*

**Nota:** Como o @bfavaretto e o @AméricoTavares disseram em Portugal também foram "aportuguesadas" algumas palavras, mas não recentemente. Algumas francesas como *camionnette* que ficou camioneta (ônibus) e algumas cidades europeias como *Milan* que ficou Milão. Eu não sei se neste último caso foi um "aportuguesar" ou não, nem se é usado no Brasil.

Comment: `Nós até usamos muitos estrangeirismos, só não "aportuguesamos" o inglês.` Embora haja tendências, acho que não há regras gerais, depende de muitas circunstâncias. Um contra-exemplo é "draubaque" muito usado há algumas décadas e  que resulta do aportuguesamento de  *drawback*, «reembolso de direitos de importação» ([infopédia](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/draubaque)). Aportuguesámos muitas palavras francesas, por exemplo, camioneta, de *camionnette*.

Comment: @AméricoTavares eu não conhecia "draubaque". O que eu quis dizer é que não é costume nosso aportuguesar palavras como se tem visto no Brasil. Amanhã revejo a resposta.

Comment: Eu achava que vocês aportuguesavam nomes como Amsterdam (para Amsterdão).

Comment: Ah nomes de cidades estrangeiras sim @bfavaretto tens razão. No Brasil não usam isso? "Nova York", "Roma", "Milão" ?

Comment: A bem da verdade, -1. Só vejo {{citation needed}} na sua resposta. Claro que o depoimento pessoal é mais que válido e necessário, assim construímos nossa história comum. Mas sem referências de outros estudiosos do passado, fico meio que a ver navios no relato de um companheiro de viagem cujas credenciais são puro 0x10010101 (igual que eu) ;)

Comment: @brasofilo é simplesmente a minha percepção da realidade. Fica a vontade de dar +/- 1

Comment: Eu estava a vontade para dar o -1 :) E leio sua resposta como pura percepção. Na vida real, a gente daria outro jeito de solucionar a questão.

Answer (score 12):

A pergunta assenta numa premissa falsa. A verdade é que os portugueses usam palavras estrangeiras ao pontapé. As palavras do domínio da computação *ficheiro, guardar, apagar*, e *rato* não mostram nenhuma aversão a palavras estrangeiras; mostram meramente que, tal como *arquivo* e *salvar* no Brasil, mesmo em domínios novos se usam palavras portuguesas. Nem outra coisa seria de esperar. (No menu do computador pode vir *correio eletrónico*, mas o que se usa em Portugal no dia-a-dia é *e-mail* ou *mail*.) Porque diferem estes termos de Portugal para o Brasil? Quase de certeza por o pessoal ter inventado e selecionado temos informáticos de forma independente no Brasil e em Portugal.

E se persistir alguma dúvida relativamente ao uso de palavras estrangeiras em Portugal, [este site lista mais de mil](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=loanwords&act=list). Aqui fica uma seleção delas começadas pela letra b; só as que eu estou mais habituado a ouvir, e excluindo importações mais antigas já aportuguesadas como bibelô, boxe ou bumerangue.

> Baby-grow, back-up, bacon, barman, bavaroise, best-seller, big-bang, bit, bitmap, blazer, blog, blogger, bluff, body, body-building, body-board, boom, box (da televisão por cabo), boxers, boy band, brandy, breakdance, browser, bug, bulldozer, bungee-jumping, bunker, byte.

Comment: De referir que estrangeirismos temos ao pontapé, mas aportuguesamentos são muitos menos. Coisas como leiaute (layout).

Comment: Sim, em Portugal tendemos a manter a grafia original.

Comment: eu escrevo **blogue** e maior parte dessa palavras, se a publicação for séria, são grafadas em itálico.

Answer (score 9):

<sup><sub><strike>[.mais opinião que fato.]</strike> - sabe o quê? Se o Vinicius de Moraes disse, pra mim é fato. *Bloody master of this language he is.*</sub></sup>
Porque no Brasil é um oba-oba tremendo <sup>`1`</sup>, o respeito à tradição não é exatamente assunto do dia e a criatividade rola  <sup>`2`</sup> solta em verso e música.

A seguinte declaração de amor de Vinicius de Moraes <sup>`3`</sup> a Portugal contém esta passagem-chave:

> ### [Amália/Vinicius - Mensagem (faixa no YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5QQ6OsgqaY)
>
> [...] Eu tenho a impressão de que o povo português precisava de se desengravatar, né ? perder assim... uma série de formalismos que ele conserva, né ?, de maneira que o que eu posso dizer ao povo português neste momento, a meus amigos portugueses que me trataram com tanto carinho, que tiveram tanta atenção comigo - inclusive uma atenção de que eu não me acho merecedor, porque eu acho que ainda também não descobri o meu caminho - é esta: despir-se do seu formalismo!
>
> Esse é o grande problema do povo português, para mim, do que eu pude verificar aqui. Integrar-se na Grande Vida, né ? num negócio que eu também não sei como explicar, mas que eu acho que é fundamental para o ser humano. Comunicar-se cada vez mais. Amar-se, amar-se, sem problemas, sofrendo muito (o sofrimento faz parte do jogo, não tem importância).
>
> Nós somos praticamente 100 milhões de seres humanos falando uma língua comum e a nossa poesia é comum de uma certa maneira. Nós temos os mesmos problemas, a mesma tristeza de conhecer o nosso semelhante de uma maneira que outros povos não conhecem, temos assim a... mesma doçura para viver, uma certa necessidade de se comunicar que outros povos não têm. Nós somos os últimos povos que amam e que cantam, né ? e que escrevem uma poesia direita, que tenta dizer qualquer coisa. [...]

<sup>[fonte transcrição](http://noparalelo23.blogspot.com.es/2013/08/mensagem.html)</sup>

Só estive em Portugal por uma semana, mas acredito que compartilha um certo espírito Ibérico aqui com a Espanha. E minha observação direta tem um bom exemplo:

- aqui todo mundo se chama Antonio, Amparo, Jose, Isabel, Pepe, Rosa, Vicente e umas outras dezenas, *pero no mucho*. Pra mim, é complicado memorizar quem é quem. Nomes criativos tipo "Shakira", só a comunidade cigana tem coragem de colocar.
- no Brasil a lista vai ser absurda e a palavra "criatividade" não é suficiente para descrever o fenômeno. Acho que só com um exemplo basta: não conheci pessoalmente, mas minha produtora contratou um cara que se chamava "Valdisnei", sim, sim, Walt Disney.

---

<sup>`1`: oba-oba: kind of african; everything goes; let's be happy and dance. tremendo: huge</sup>

<sup>`2`: rolar: to roll; street meaning is "going on"</sup>

<sup>`3`: The Girl of Ipanema writer. *Please, read, hear, this man.*</sup>

Comment: Nem 8 nem 80 amigo. Acho um exagero o que acontece no Brasil. Os nomes que se deixam por até me arrepiam, tipo esse do seu exemplo. Leiaute é outro caso que me arrepia. Acho que aqui andamos engravatados demais e ai (Brasil) engravatados de menos. 
Esse caso especifico de nomes é falta de hábito, aqui há muitos nomes iguais é fácil de decorar o nome de quem.

Comment: Não tenho problema nenhum em usar a linguagem criativamente nem em aceitar neologismos ou transmutações da palavra. Gosto do espírito americano (da Patagônia ao Alaska) de não estar nem aí para o que diz a "Real Academia de la Lengua". Também não tenho problema com a formalidade e classicismo europeu, me divirto também :)

Comment: Eu sou sincero gosto muito do português antigo e sou uma pessoa de tradições :)

Comment: @JorgeB. cuidado para não soar assim: `Eu sou syncero gosto muinto do pertuguês antigo e soy unha persona de tradiçoms.`

Comment: PS: é minha opinião que o Brasil é um oba-oba tremendo, mas também estou para encontrar, de maneira geral, gente tão profissional como conheço dali. Os Alemães, a galera dos States, gente *über-professional*, mas infelizmente sem oba-oba :P

Comment: @JorgeB., pesquisando um vídeo, encontrei um nome em que a criatividade manda lembranças e o mau gosto assume o volante: [Hitler Cézar](http://www.manhuacunews.com.br/2015/08/17/divino-colisao-quase-termina-em-tragedia/), reporter que assina a matéria.

Comment: @JorgeB. Os nomes próprios inventados por aqui também me arrepiam. Hoje em dia os cartórios são um pouco menos liberais mas até uns 50 anos atrás valia tudo: "Ava Gina", "Caio Rolando", "Eva Gina", e milhares de outros que nem engraçados são. São simplesmente feios.

Comment: A bem longo prazo, é bem provável que muitas linguas desapareçam da face da terra.  O Português não está ameaçado porque somos mais de 200 milhões de falantes.  Acho que evitar os estrangeirismos, as "loan words" é uma forma de carinho para com a língua.  Se nós não cuidarmos de nossa língua, ela se descaracteriza.  Sempre foi assim, a língua do país hegemônico se impõe aos demais.  Foi o caso de Roma, do Francês e atualmente da língua Inglesa.

Answer (score 6):

O Português do Brasil incorpora mais facilmente os anglicismos: time para *team*, *freezer*, *mouse*, etc. O grande problema, no meu entender como falante da variante Europeia, é alguma inconsistência fonética.

Grafa-se *mouse* mas le-se *máuze*, o que é, à luz da fonética da língua portuguesa, europeia ou brasileira, muito incoerente. Por isso, é mais comum na variante europeia da língua, não adotar anglicismos que não se enquadrem na fonética. Quando os mesmos são adaptáveis, usamo-los, como *estandardização* ou *clube*, um aportuguesamento de *club*.

Quando na variante europeia o aportuguesamento fica demasiado estranho, adotamos a variante inglesa em itálico, mas nem sempre: *layout* mas Internet.

Resumidamente: os Brasileiros são mais criativos e liberais na criação de neologismos e os Portugueses são mais conservadores.

PS: *stress* em Portugal, estresse no Brasil. Neste ponto concordo com o aportuguesamento, mas mouse para rato, acho inadequado quando mouse em inglês antes da invenção do computador já significava rato.

Comment: Os teus exemplos são muito bons, excelente resposta,

Comment: Acho que não traduzem mouse para rato pois não gostam de chamá-lo de rato.

Comment: @AndréLyra e qual é o problema em chamá-lo de rato? _Mouse_ em Inglês não é rato? Os ingleses, estadunidenses, australianos, canadianos ou irlandeses não têm problemas em chamá-lo de rato, na sua própria língua.

Comment: A palavra Internet, com "i" maiúsculo, não é usada em itálico porque é uma rede de computadores em específico. Há também a *internet*, que é o conceito (no [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet) há uma nota sobre isso). Esta sim provavelmente é escrita em itálico, já que é uma palavra em inglês.

Answer (score 4):

Idealmente não se usariam estrangeirismos visto que estes normalmente são incongruentes com a nossa ortografia e morfologia da nossa lingua.

No entanto a lingua é uma criação social e nem sempre um aportuguesamento ou a alternativa em português é aceite pelos falantes, que acabam a usar o estrangeirismo (aportuguesado ou não).

Sendo o português do Brasil e de Portugal pertencentes a comunidades linguisticas relativamente afastadas, é natural que por vezes os estrangeirismos sejam aceites de diferentes formas em cada lado do Atlantico.

Answer (score -1):

Porque o estrangeirismo molda a língua falada no Brasil, falamos brasileiro e não português e o estrangeirismo molda o idioma brasileiro. Filmes, novelas, desenhos e até entrevistas portugueses tem que ter legendas no Brasil ou ser dublados, porque já são duas línguas diferentes.

Comment: Crisdilayne, bem-vinda ao site. Mas olha que a língua falada do Brasil ser ou não moldada por estrangeirismos, não tem nada que ver com usarem-se ou não muitos estrangeirismos em Portugal, que é o assunto da pergunta.