# Qual é o artigo correto em palavras em outras línguas?

Tags: gramática, tradução, tradução-inglês

Qual o artigo usar quando usamos uma palavra em inglês que não tem uma clara tradução para o português?

Citando um exemplo: é "o" *thread* ou é "a" *thread*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não creio que em geral exista critério para decidir o género *correto* duma palavra estrangeira. Temos que esperar até que o uso consagre o masculino ou o feminino. Dito isto, andei por aí a ver o género preferido de substantivos estrangeiros que já cá andam há algum tempo, e encontrei uma preferência clara pelo género masculino. As exceções que encontrei são palavras que têm em português claramente um equivalente do género feminino (*box, play list, boy band*) e palavras que são femininas na língua original (*bavaroise, piza*).

Fiz um Google search em todos os sites (ao contrário do Artefacto, que viu só em sites *.pt* e *.br*) de frases em português. Depois vi a primeira página de resultados para ver se havia resultados em línguas estrangeiras ou falsos positivos em geral.

Curiosamente os meus resultados (todos em milhares), ao contrário dos do Artefacto, mostram uma preferência, mas não esmagadora, por *thread* masculino. A exceção é *outra thread*, ligeiramente mais numerosas que *outro thread*. Vi a primeira página de resultados, e o contexto é sempre programação. Imagino que as outras frases apanhem sobretudo *treads* com significado de discussão, o que sugere uma possível diferença entre programadores não programadores.

```
                      Feminino   Masculino
Outra/outro thread      33,6        28,9
Um/uma thread           84,9       157
Um/uma thread sobre      7,83       20
O/a thread sobre         4,93       21,2
Esse/essa thread        32,40       80
Vi um/uma thread         3,13       11
Vários/Várias threads    7,2        23,4
```

Para a pesquisa geral, procurei as palavras estrangeiras duma lista que tinha elaborado há uns meses para [esta resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/582/por-que-o-idioma-portugu%C3%AAs-portugal-n%C3%A3o-aceita-muitas-palavras-estrangeiras-exe/1242#1242) (o que significa que não as escolhi por serem masculina ou femininas), e juntei-lhes *play list* e *playstation* por suspeitar serem femininas,  já que têm equivalentes femininos em português. Mas a *playstation* trocou-me as voltas: é preferencialmente masculino. Parece-me que isto se deve ao Brasil, e que em Portugal o género feminino é o preferido. Para muitas das palavras preferencialmente masculinas existe um equivalente português masculino, mas para muitas outras não existe (*blog, bluff, boom, Big Bang*, etc.). Para *um/uma bodyboard, break dance* e *buldózer* o equivalente português é até feminino (*prancha, dança, retroescavadora*) e ainda assim a palavra foi para o masculino. Parece haver mesmo uma preferência pelo masculino.

```
                        Fem.    Masc.                           Fem.   Masc.
Liguei a/o box           2,6     0,0     Comprei um/a body       1,0     3,1
As/os boy bands         12,4     0,2     Um/a body board         0,1     1,2
Uma/um bavaroise         1,7     0,3     Um/a bodyboard          0,6     3,4
Uma/um playlist        389,0    33,9     Um/a boom               1,6   272,0
Um/uma playstation      26,7   286,6     Comprei uns/as boxers   0,0     0,2
Um/a baby grow/babygrow  0,0     3,5     Um/a brandy -moto(s)    0,3     8,8
Um/uma backup/back up    5,6   483,0     O/a breakdance foi+é    0,1     1,2
Muito/muita bacon        0,1    19,8     Um/a browser            0,8   397,0
Sobre o/a Big Bang      29,4    92,8     Um/a bug                2,8   472,0
Muitos/as bits           0,0     4,1     Um/a bul(l)dózer        1,1     8,4
Um/a bitmap              0,7    21,1     O/a bungee-jumping é    0,0     1,1
Vesti um/a blazer        0,0     1,3     Um/a bunker             0,5    76,4
Um/a blog sobre          2,1   549,0     Um/a byte               0,3    57,9
Um/a blogue sobre        0,0    37,7
Um/a bluff               0,2    15,0
```

Comment: Acho que o facto de teres alargado a pesquisa a todos os sites enviesou os resultados. Quando passamos a primeira página de "um thread" só se vê lixo. Quando restringimos os resultados a uma população apropriada, a tendência é clara para o feminino. Compara `site:pt.stackoverflow.com "uma thread"` (833) com `site:pt.stackoverflow.com "uma thread"` (167).

Comment: @Artefacto Foi por isso que eu vi as outras frases mais longas.

Comment: E já agora, dizer que «o género preferido de substantivos estrangeiros que já cá andam há algum tempo, e encontrei uma preferência clara pelo género masculino» só por si não prova que existe uma tendência para atribuir o masculino indepedentemente de outras considerações como a palavra portuguesa mais próxima, temos de comparar, em primeiro lugar com a proporção das outras palavras ou (melhor) com as palavras portuguesas mais próximas.

Comment: Parece que no Brasil há tendência para usar o masculino quando se trata de _thread_ no contexto de um fórum/e-mail (mas não no contexto de programação). Se limitarmos os resultados a `.pt` ou `site:pt.stackoverflow.com`, o feminino tem consistentemente ~5x mais resultados.

Comment: @Artefacto Foi isso que eu fiz no último parágrafo. Que considerações é que tu vês para *bluff, blog, Big Bang* ou *boom* serem masculinos?

Comment: @Artefacto A respeito de *thread*, não tive a ver se havia diferenças entre Brasil e Portugal, mas pelos meus resultados suspeitei que houvesse uma diferença entre programadores e não programadores; ou entre programação e fóruns. Imagino que frases como *vi um/a thread* ou *thead sobre* sejam pouco comuns em programação.

Comment: Para _Big Bang_, _boom_, temos _estrondo_, _explosão_. _Bodyboard_ é primariamente um desporto, não sei sequer se se aplica à prancha em si. De qualquer forma, não duvido que o masculino é o género por omissão por parecer menos marcado. Apenas estava a questionar 1) os métodos (fazer uma generalização a partir de meia dúzia de dados) e 2) a pouca consideração dada aos outros fatores.

Comment: Certo.​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @Artefacto Eu descrevo o que observei. Se tu tiveres uma explicação, que poderá muito bem existir, baseada nos tais outros fatores para explicar os meus resultados, e terei todo o interesse em apreciá-la. Repara também que eu trabalhei com uma lista de palavra pré-definida; não as andei a escolher. O que elas têm em comum é começarem por ***b***, o que não creio que enviese os resultados.

Comment: @Artefacto Eu procurei *um/uma boadyboard*: em todos os resultados da primeira página, o significado é *prancha*, como seria de esperar.

Comment: A pronúncia também pode marcar essa definição. Thread, parece uma palavra feminina. Bodyboard com esses ó parece masculina.

Comment: @AndréLyra *Thread* pode parecer-te a ti uma palavra feminina, mas como podes ver pelos meus números, na maioria dos resultados no google search, ela é usada como masculina.

Answer (score 6):

A regra é tomar o nome de uma palavra análoga em português que esteja mais ou menos próxima (pode por exemplo ser um hiperónimo). O género adotado também pode estar relacionado com características morfológicas, por exemplo um *-a* final tenderá a levar a palavra para o feminino. Poderá ser o caso em: *influenza*, *cantata*, *coloratura*, *datcha*, *troika*, ...

Em relação a *thread*, temos duas boas traduções, *fio* e *linha*, de dois géneros diferentes. Eu sempre ouvi (e disse) ***a** thread* (no sentido em que é usada em informática). Restringindo a sites `.pt`, o Google apresenta esta contagem de resultados, que confirma de certa forma  a minha experiência:

> `site:pt "um thread"`:  1370
>   `site:pt "uma thread"`:  6750 (5x)

A tendência é a mesma para sites `.br`, embora menos marcada:

> `site:br "um thread"`:  5540
>   `site:br "uma thread"`:  16600 (3x)

Answer (score 4):

Existem ínfimas palavras da língua inglesa que realmente não têm tradução em português. Normalmente o uso do vernáculo estrangeiro se dá por dois motivos:

1. Falta de domínio na língua portuguesa (ou falta de domínio com ferramentas de busca/dicionários online na língua portuguesa).
2. Costumes e jargões técnicos.
3. Modismos. Normalmente a palavra é "aportuguesada".

Note que no Brasil há uma tolerância muito maior do que em Portugal no tocante ao uso de estrangeirismos. Mas ainda assim, depende do círculo social em que o discurso está inserido.

Em situações que a versão culta da língua é recomendada o recomendado é buscar exaustivamente a tradução.

Em casos como no item 2, normalmente costuma-se concordar o artigo com a tradução em português. No seu exemplo:

*Thread* pode significar linha. Linha é substantivo feminino. Logo, a concordância é no feminino. Neste sentido, usa-se linha.

No jargão de programadores, *Thread* quer dizer uma linha de execução do programa, [uma tarefa](http://www.tecmundo.com.br/9669-o-que-sao-threads-em-um-processador-.htm). Então é comum em conversas coloquiais entre programadores, usar:

> Este *breakpoint* parou a *thread* na linha onde a exceção foi lançada.

Aqui, *breakpoint* significa "ponto de parada", uma marca no código para que o programa executando em modo de *debug* (depuração) interrompa o processo (*thread*) ao passar por aquele.

Mas este diálogo trata-se de coloquialismo, aceito no meio técnico. Ainda assim, todos os termos têm tradução. Veja que a construção gramatical se aproxima do esperado pela língua inglesa. Se os termos traduzidos fossem inseridos, a frase ficaria confusa:

> Este ponto de **parada parou** a tarefa na linha onde a exceção foi lançada.

Seria desejável:

> A tarefa [*thread*] foi interrompido pelo ponto de parada [*breakpoint*] na linha onde a exceção foi lançada.

Por fim, é melhor usar o estilo itálico ao invés das aspas para dar destaque a palavras estrangeiras.

Comment: `Processo` é diferente de `thread` (embora sejam conceitos próximos, inclusive em Linux -- o kernel -- não é feita distinção), por isso não podes simplesmente substituir as duas palavras, como fizeste no último exemplo.

Comment: @Artefacto qual seria então a melhor tradução de thread no contexto da computação?

Comment: Não me lembra alguma vez ter visto traduzido.

Comment: Não me recordo de alguma vez ter visto "o thread", em contextos de programação. Mesmo na literatura oficial de faculdades, normalmente se trata como "a thread", em casos onde o material foi traduzido (na minha experiência ao menos!)

Comment: @ThalesPereira sim, tens razão. Achei fontes traduzindo "thread" por tarefa / linha de execução. Vou usar esta.

Comment: Não é muito clara a diferença de processo e tarefa, mas geralmente processo é um conjunto de instruções diversas ou de tarefas; e tarefa um conjunto de instruções semelhantes.

Answer (score 0):

Para melhor completar essa discussão antiga, mas que é ainda um dos poucos resultados de busca sobre o uso correto de artigos de gênero em termos estrangeiros, falta distinguir o termo da informática e termo das redes sociais.

"A thread" parece mais adequado para o termo de informática por substituir "linha".

Ao mesmo tempo "o thread" é o mais adequado para fóruns de discussão por substituir "tópico".

No Brasil o volume de utilização de fóruns em redes sociais é muito maior que em Portugal, considerado por óbvio a população. Por isso os resultados concernentes ao gênero masculino são maiores, pois trata-se do uso do termo relacionado a tópicos de discussão.