# Idêntico significa «parecido» ou «exactamente igual»?

Tags: significado, diferenças-transatlânticas

Estava a falar com uns amigos Brasileiros e para eles [idêntico](https://dicionario.priberam.org/identico) é «exatamente igual», quase como um exagero de igual. No meu entender idêntico significa «parecido» ou muito parecido.

Por exemplo:

> Ele tem um irmão gémeo que é idêntico a ele.
>
> Ele tem um carro idêntico ao meu, só muda a cor.
>
> A voz dele é idêntica à do ator.

Afinal **idêntico** é «exatamente igual» ou «parecido» ou os dois?

Comment: Sou brasileiro, e realmente muitas vezes usamos idêntico como "exatamente igual" (não o mesmo indivíduo), mas me parece que geralmente por aqui variamos conforme o "contexto", posso estar equivocado também. Por exemplo gêmeos idênticos, não são de fato *"exatamente iguais"*, tem digitais (e ondas cerebrais :P) próprias ... No entanto já ouvi muito alguém comparar 2 resultados como idênticos, mas obtidos por "ferramentas" diferentes, por exemplo um produto de limpeza que usa toda a mesma base que outro produto, então me parece que não é bem o caso de "exatamente igual", depende de como emprega.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento parece que sim, que depende do contexto, mas para mim, em qualquer contexto idêntico nunca seria exatamente igual. Pode até ser regionalismo, não sei.

Comment: Ouvi dizer, posso ter entendido errado, que portugueses são bastante literais, algo que costuma não ser comum entre os brasileiros, algo mais por cultura do que idioma, então realmente creio que esteja certo, mas justamente por não sermos tão literais que acabamos usando em diferentes contextos (com propósitos diferentes).

Comment: Para mim (pt-br) idêntico também é "exatamente igual", e o caso de "gêmeos idênticos" é um expressão fixa apenas, para diferenciar os univitelinos dos gêmeos fraternos.

Comment: @stafusa citei gêmeos como exemplo, mas também citei outras situações, e creio que posso citar mais, aonde o idêntico é empregado quando não é "exatamente igual" e situações aonde é "exatamente igual"

Comment: **PS:** Acho que a culpa disto tudo é da [documentação do PHP: `$a == $b` (igual) e `$a === $b` (Idêntico)](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php) ... Já a documentação da MDN: Igual (`==`) e Estritamente igual (`===`). Culpa é sempre do PHP mesmo. (ps²: é piada :D)

Comment: Eu moro na região central do Rio Grande do Sul (estado mais ao sul do Brasil), e sempre encarei "idêntico" como algo muito parecido a outra coisa e, como as pessoas com quem converso também, acredito que seja algo regional.

Comment: Levei em conta teu comentário, @fernandosavio, na última atualização da minha resposta.

Comment: Parecido é diferente de idêntico

Comment: @ClMend depende da região e do contexto. Vê a resposta a baixo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Os dicionários são claros: ambos os sentidos são aceitáveis. Por exemplo o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/id%C3%AAntico), o [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/id%C3%AAntico/) e a [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/id%C3%AAntico) dão:

> 1 Que é exatamente igual (gêmeos idênticos, roupa idêntica) [ Antôn.: diferente ]
>   2 Que é muito parecido ou análogo: colonização idêntica à dos espanhóis.
>
> 1 Que é o mesmo que o outro.
>   2 Perfeitamente igual.
>   3 Que é muito parecido; semelhante.
>
> 1 o mesmo que outro; igual
>   2 semelhante nas características essenciais; análogo; parecido

Pessoalmente, em linguagem coloquial só vi sendo usado (pt-br) no sentido de "exatamente igual", mas outros falantes de pt-br atestam conhecerem o uso como "semelhante", portanto mais que uma diferença transatlântica, parece se tratar de regionalismo.

A Infopédia, por exemplo, [define](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/identidade) **identidade** como "*paridade ou igualdade absoluta*". E o Priberam define: **paridade** =  "Qualidade do que é *igual* ou semelhante."; **identidade** = "*Paridade* absoluta."; **idêntico** = "Que tem com outro uma relação de *identidade*." Ou seja, se essas cadeias de definições fossem confiáveis (na verdade elas podem quebrar), temos dela: **idêntico = igualdade absoluta** como uma das possibilidades de acordo com o Priberam também (que tem como definições principais "muito parecido; aparentemente igual").

Vale mencionar que, tanto em matemática quanto em (até onde sei) filosofia, "**identidade**" indica muito mais que similaridade perfeita: indica que se trata do mesmo objeto. Ou seja, "A é idêntico a B" significaria que A e B são dois nomes para a mesma coisa.

Já no uso cotidiano, uma [análise similar](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-sinonimia-entre-identico-e-igual/17510) no Ciberdúvidas, que considera um número maior de dicionários (apontada pelo [Jorge B.](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/153)), lembra da etimologia de "idêntico" (que é "idem" = "o mesmo", "igual") e ao mesmo tempo reconhece o uso como "parecido", concluindo também que:

> é evidente que não podemos ter a ousadia de afirmar e/ou pensar que **idêntico** só tem um significado.

Comment: Também vale comentar que o inglês "*identical*" significa apenas "o mesmo" ou "exatamente igual". Por exemplo, no [thefreedictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/identical): **1.** Being the same: *another orator who used the senator's identical words.*
**2.** Exactly equal and alike: *Your car is identical to mine. Are the fingerprints at the crime scene identical with those of the accused?*

Comment: A resposta está boa, mas ficaria mais sólida ainda com referências a um dicionário pt-PT. :) Isto porque a pergunta não é sobre português-brasileiro, é sobre diferenças transatlânticas.

Answer (score 1):

Em pt-BR

Independente do que digam os dicionários, quando alguém me diz que algo é **"idêntico"**, eu entendo que é **"exatamente igual"**. Duas coisas podem até não ser cem por cento iguais, mas quem usa a palavra "idêntico" quer transmitir que "são exatamente iguais". Em outras palavras, posso dizer que são idênticos porque são iguais de ponta a ponta, ou porque duas coisas são tão parecidas que quero até exagerar e dizer que são idênticas.

"Idêntico" seria uma forma de excluir o "muito parecido" e afirmar que é "exatamente igual".

Em tempo: gêmeos idênticos são aqueles que tiveram sua origem em um único óvulo fecundado e têm código genético idêntico. Já o fenótipo não é o que está em questão quando se trata de uma discussão científica.

Comment: Concordo. Mas o OP deixa claro que em pt-PT é diferente, talvez por isso as diferentes definições dos dicionários.

Comment: Também sou brasileiro e quando me dizem "idêntico" entendendo como o AP. Deve ser algo regional mesmo.

Comment: @stafusa, nestes casos o que faço é ir ao dicionário Latim e Alemão. Porquê? Em especial o Alemão, é um exemplo de rigor na definição das palavras. Querem saber o que diz o verbete de igual? Diz isto:"Igual, significa inteiramente idêntico". (As irmãs Michaëlis decerto não concordariam com algumas das opções que hoje figuram no dicionáro de seu nome.)

Comment: @bad_coder Pesquisar noutras línguas pode ajudar mesmo, mas, nesse caso, como ter certeza de que o significado em, digamos, alemão, é o mesmo que em português? Como comentei na minha resposta, o inglês também é bem claro que idêntico significa "o mesmo" ou "exatamente igual". Mas o OP e Fernando mostram que em português há dialetos que entendem de outra forma.

Answer (score -2):

É curioso notar que até na matemática os conceitos de "igual" e "idêntico" são diferentes.

> ≡ idêntico [barra tripla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_bar)
>
> = igual [barra dupla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(mathematics))

Como a palavra sugere, igual é igual, enquanto idêntico não sendo igual implica alguma diferença.

O problema é que se começamos a relaxar o significado dado às palavras, algum dia já o dicionário não diz o que a palavra significa mas só como se usa. O que depois só traz mais problemas...É de evitar, acho, enquanto amante da língua, participar nessas tendências. Penso que a maior parte dos dicionários do Português nas nunaces das suas escolhas, indicam uma clara visão dos lexicólogos em relação ao que merece ser lexicalizado, ou não, e à definição das possibilidades semánticas de cada palavra. Talvez caiba-nos a nós, falantes com alguma erudição, contribuir no quotidiano do nosso falar para a conservação de uma herança linguística que julgo sã.

**EDIT**: Para quem aprecia os nomes próprios dados a um debate antigo: [Prescritivismo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription)

Comment: "idêntico não sendo igual implica alguma diferença" Isso não é correto. Ou você teria alguma fonte que afirme isso? Uma identidade é, por exemplo, uma igualdade que se verifica sempre.

Comment: Queria, de facto, comentar a tua reposta @stafusa. Não o fiz antes, é agora. Mas quero ressalvar, direi o seguinte com genuína fraternidade -sem qualquer chauvinismo, cultural ou linguístico- antes, com neutralidade. Pedes provas? Muito bem! Que provas convenceriam por sua inerente autoridade? Se fores ao priberam, vês que idêntico não figura nas definições/sinonímia de igual. Tanto não é por acaso. Então, talvez, a pergunta será: porquê? Porquê tal discrepância entre os dicionários? É uma boa pergunta, pertinente, em seguimento do que em conjunto aqui contrastamos.

Comment: bad_coder, sem stress - a discussão é saudável. Se você notar, também noutras questões é comum se pedir fontes e referências no SE - sobre autoridade, normalmente se aplicam (leve e livremente) os critérios usuais de confiabilidade. No caso do meu comentário em particular, eu me referia apenas ao sentido matemático, que me é bem familiar e que não concorda com tua afirmação - então um verbete da Wikipedia, Wolfram, etc. estaria de bom tamanho, até porque é uma questão um pouco tangente à do OP.

Comment: Sobre o Priberam, que também uso com frequência, veja como ele define: **paridade** =  "Qualidade do que é *igual* ou semelhante."; **identidade** = "*Paridade* absoluta."; **idêntico** = "Que tem com outro uma relação de *identidade*." Ou seja, se essas cadeias de definições fossem confiáveis (na verdade elas podem quebrar), temos dela: **idêntico = igualdade absoluta** como uma das possibilidades de acordo com o Priberam também.

Comment: @stafusa e bad_coder como uma vez me disse o user [@brasofilo](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/582/por-que-o-portugu%c3%aas-europeu-n%c3%a3o-incorpora-muitos-estrangeirismos/589#comment1414_589), a língua está em constante mudança e não há verdades absolutas. Senão ainda falávamos como Camões.

Comment: JorgeB e stafusa Fiz um edit ao meu post que remete para a história dos princípios subjacentes a este debate. Devo dizer, gostei da pesquisa do @stafusa em perseguir os termos paridade->identidade->idêntico no dicionário, é o método que também costumo usar. Mas, há certos aspectos que podemos ressalvar, por exemplo: a polémica muito comum nos EUA sobre os novos pronomes pessoais de género neutro...Acho esse exemplo interessante, por ser fracturante e, inserir-se numa problemática muito mais vasta. É so um exemplo...Suponho que sou um bocado conservador em relação às palavras.